# Is possible to install Windows 10 to a bootable USB pendrive?

Tags: macos, windows-10, usb-flash-drive

I'mm looking forward to buy a mac with 256GB SSD, which I want to preserve for the operating system.
If I want to have Windows 10 and runt it from a SSD Pendrive like the Corsair Flash Voyager GTX, would that be possible? I know that linux can be installed and run as portable for a Flash drive.

Comment: [4 Tools To Create Windows To Go USB Of Windows 10](http://www.intowindows.com/4-tools-to-create-windows-to-go-usb-of-windows-10/)

Comment: Downvoted, since you could easily have searched for this on the internet.

Comment: @Smeterlink - Users are encouraged to vote on questions an answers, voting is helpful to the community, a question or answer with lots of votes a good thing.  I won't be submitting an answer at this time, but [Rufus](http://rufus.akeo.ie), has the ability to create a "Windows to Go" drive.  I am hesistant to even answer this question, because of your attitude towards voting in general, I am even afraid I will be attacked for voting on this question honestly.

Comment: @Ramhound Rufus if for creating installation media. What I am looking for is to install Windows 10 directly on the pendrive like a normal operating system, to use daily, do video editing with Adobe Premiere and things like that.

Comment: @Smeterlink - It can also be used to make "Windows to Go" drives.  I have used it before specifcally for that purpose.

Answer (score -1):

You require Windows to Go for this, which in turn requires the Enterprise/Education edition. You may also mount an image on the drive and boot from it.

Comment: Can you walk the user, who does not know how to create a Windows to Go drive, the process of doing so?

Comment: NO!!! So many guides are available for this. Superuser is not a site made for answering questions that have already been answered all over the web.

Comment: Superuser is specfically around to answer questions, and without instructions on how to do it, if I didn't alreadyknow how to do it I couldn't use your answer to solve this problem if I had it.  I am sorry you feel that way, that Superuser isn't around for answering questions, that have been answered all over the web because the majority of the answers on this website are to questions that have already been answered some place else.